# Difference between Layer and LayerInstance

Tags: r, ggplot2

Whenever you make a layer in ggplot2 through a `geom_*()` or `stat_*()` function**, it returns a `"LayerInstance", "Layer", "ggproto", "gg"` class object. My question is: what is the difference between a LayerInstance and Layer object? Are there Layer objects that aren't LayerInstance?

My use case is determining whether a user has supplied a function with a valid layer object.

```r
library(ggplot2)

is.layer1 <- function(x) {
  inherits(x, "Layer")
}

is.layer2 <- function(x) {
  inherits(x, "LayerInstance")
}

is.layer1(geom_point())
#> [1] TRUE

is.layer2(geom_point())
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Which one would be more robust, `is.layer1` or `is.layer2`?

** `geom_sf()` returns a `list()` and is the only exception I know of.

Comment: There's an internal `ggplot2:::is.layer` function that looks like your `is.layer1`, and no sign in the source of any uses of `LayerInstance`, so I'd go with `is.layer1`.

Comment: Thanks, that is useful to know!